# Cannot add pointer to array of class pointers vector

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I am trying to add a pointer to an object in a pointer object vector. The 'message_list' vector lists pointers to an abstract class Message which is either adding a new Topic or Reply, two subclasses which inherit the superclass Message.
My problem is when I try to add either a new Topic or a Reply to the vector, I get an error at compile time

> error: no matching function for call to `‘std::vector<Message*, std::allocator<Message*> >::push_back(Topic*&) const’`
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:602: note: candidates are: `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&)`
> [with `_Tp` = `Message*`, `_Alloc` = `std::allocator<Message*>`] `<near match>`

The error is on the line with the `messag_list.push_back(msg)`:

```
Message* msg = new Topic( current_user->get_username(), subject, body, (message_list.size()+1) );
message_list.push_back(msg);
```

Why can't I add this pointer to my pointer vector?
Thank you for the help!

EDIT:
Here is the full function:

```
void Bboard::add_topic() const
{
    string subject;
    cout << "Enter Subject: ";
    cin >> subject;
    
    string body;
    cout << "Enter Body: ";
    cin >> body;
    
    Message* msg = new Topic( current_user->get_username(), subject, body, (message_list.size()+1) );

    message_list.push_back(msg);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Message Recorded!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: How is `message_list` declared? also you are trying to do this from a `const` member function?

Comment: The compiler seems to be looking for a `const` function to call Is `message_list` possibly a parameter passed by const reference?

Comment: @Bo Persson: I also suspect that.

Comment: Thanks Naveen! It was a problem with const. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Bboard::add_topic() const
```

Its a const member function  which means this function promises not to *modify* the object, but the fact is that you want to modify the object, as `message_list` is a member of the class and you're adding item to it. So `const` is inappropriate here. Just remove it and make it as:

```
void Bboard::add_topic();
```

Problem solved!

A little more explanation :

In a const member function, every member of the class becomes const, unless its declared with the keyword `mutable`, so in your const member function, `message_list` is const object, so when you want to call `push_back` on this object, the compiler generates error, because `push_back` function can be called only on non-const object.

Comment: Yes, `Topic` is derived from `Message`.

Comment: Topic::Topic(const string& athr, const string& sbjct, const string& body, unsigned id)
    :Message(athr, sbjct, body, id)
    {}

Comment: Message::Message(const string& athr, const string& sbjct, const string& body, unsigned id) :author(athr), subject(sbjct), body(body), id(id) {}

Comment: @MikeTrottman: Post in your question, not here. I can't read it here. I'm not a compiler. Also, these code doesn't help. Post MORE code, not just the constructor!